# FFMPEG Live Stream Capturing: Any option to find stream is down?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am capturing live video stream using ffmpeg through the following command:

ffmpeg -re -i STREAM_URL -t 3600 c:/test.mp4

Is there any opetion in ffmpeg that generate a message whenever the stream is down

Comment: you probably shouldn't use "-re" to capture a live stream (it's actually for the opposite, to broadcast a non live input "in realtime" to the output). if you run `ffmpeg -i input` (with no output) that might give you a hint (if it's able to decipher the media type, you know at least it can connect OK) FWIW

Comment: have you tried 'stimeout' option?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on input's streaming type. you must define first what type of streaming is allowed in your work(such as HLS, RTMP)

When the streaming URL is really unavailable while in streaming, in general situation, FFmpeg just returns EOF flag so you really don't know whether streaming is down, or just end.

It could be more complicated in live streaming. when streaming URL is alive but no stream is pushed into input streaming URL, it just waiting forever without any message.

Funny thing is that you still can catch only few things in above situation in source code level. So there is really no way to know whether stream is down, or whatever if you're just using command-line. You must check server too.

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -benchmark -t 00:00:30 -s 1280x720 -i video0 -b 5000k -report c:/main/sample.avi
```

Run it on `CMD` it will capture live video of 30 seconds and save it along with report.